# How to put where clauses in an inner join clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, db2, h2

I am joining a few tables and in each join, I have to specify a specific condition.

```
SELECT * FROM
table1
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.id WHERE table2.column1 = 'horse'
INNER JOIN table3
ON table2.id = table3.id WHERE table3.column1 = 'cow';
```

I get a sql syntax error. When I remove the where statements, it starts working again. How am I able to solve this?

Comment: where clause should be only after all joins

Answer (score 3):

Change your `where`s on the joins to `and`s:

```
SELECT * FROM
table1
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.id AND table2.column1 = 'horse'
INNER JOIN table3
ON table2.id = table3.id AND table3.column1 = 'cow';
```

Answer (score 1):

There's just one `WHERE` clause for the entire query, they're not associated with joins. Use `AND` or `OR` to combine them.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.id = table3.id 
WHERE table3.column1 = 'cow' AND table2.column1 = 'horse'
```

Comment: This works, but sadly full stack's answer is more likely what they meant, and how you have to do it for left joins.

Comment: @ysth I was thinking of mentioning that left joins are a special case, but I didn't want to complicate the answer.